MacBook Pro 8,2 (2011) Trackpad Issues w/XUbubtu 24.04
I just finished installing xubuntu on my 2011 MacBook Pro (8,2) and am running into some serious bugs with the trackpad. It will work fine and allow me to fluidly move the cursor… and then start to stutter and act like I am perpetually right clicking. Is there an updated driver for this MacBook Pro touchpad I need to install? Any help or insights are welcome. Thanks!
